# Graph of Sum from pivot table

Tags: excel, graph, sum, pivot-table, pie-chart

I am trying to make Pie Graph which shows sums from my Pivot table. But it only shows data from 01.01.2018 or other date. Does somebody know a solution? Thanks :)

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyo0n.png)

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you want to achieve but perhaps look into  GETPIVOTDATA formulas (select any cell in pivot then select ribbon Analyze tab/Options/Generate get pivotdata). They refer to an intersection within the pivot, which should be more stable to build the source data for a graph.

Comment: Yes thats right :) Many thanks:)